# Gitlab issue with git push

Tags: git, gitlab, bitnami

Having issues doing a git push from both git cli and gitlab http interface.

Can't seem to figure out where the issue is.  Had gitlab server behind nginx proxy which I thought may have been causing the issue but removed nginx and now have 1:1 nat rule created.  I have same issue when testing internally on same subnet with no natting.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLQwD.png]

Comment: What is your host and gitlab version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be related to [issue 1716](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1716)

> Turned out to be the behaviour you get if any of the directories in the `gitlab-shell` `repos_path` were **symlinks** (in our case on freebsd, `/home` being used when that is a symlink to `/usr/home`).
>   Putting in the absolute path without symlinks allows us to push over SSH as expected. The same thing affected us in the HTTPS setup as well.
>
> I confirm that changing the path to `/usr/home` in `gitlab-shell/config.yml` solve the problem for me
>
> I had the same issue when I tried to use a soft link for `git-data`:

Check your gitlab-shell.
For instance: [issue 3787](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3787):

> My fault.. GitLab hostname was wrong in `gitlab-shell/config.yml` and `gitlab.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I am using bitnami appliance and symlink'd /opt/bitnami to /mnt/sdb1/bitnami to relocate install, once I modified the repo_path to /mnt/sdb1/bitnami/... everything is working.  Of course it is clearly commented in the config.yml that # REPOS_PATH MUST NOT CONTAIN ANY SYMLINK!!! Thanks for the direction, saved me bunch of time trying to ferret out the root cause on my own.